# How can i know if a page is accessed from web browser or mobile device

Tags: jquery

I have a code (**HTML pages with javascript and css**)that can be used from web browser or mobile device .

In case the page is accessed from mobile/tablet i need to load phonegap's corodava js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="cordava.js"></script>');

});
```

My question is how can i know if a page is accessed from browser or a  Mobile device  /tablet??

Comment: You could use [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to check if the device is touch enabled, there are also plugins for [checking platform](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mobile-detect)

Comment: what will you do with cordova.js if it is accessed via web